# PHP SQL database query error

Tags: php, mysql

im having trouble with a seemingly correct query for mysql database. The Query in question is:

> "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email =".$email.";". The Query itself is
>   executing fine but the $result that is returned back is false (if i
>   replace "Email =".$email."" with "Id = 1" it works and returns a
>   value).

```
  if($emailCheck = TRUE){
               echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Email check true.');</script>";
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email =".$email.";";
               echo $sql;
               $result = $conn->query($sql);
               if ($result){
                  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;
                  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".(string)$row['FirstName']."');</script>"; 
               } else { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('bad result');</script>";}
           }
```

Some info:

- $emailCheck = TRUE is working fine.
- When using "Id = 1" instead of "Email =".$email."" everything works
- echo $sql; returns "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email =zxzx@hotmail.com;"

any help why $result is returned false when using "Email =".$email.""?

Comment: try "Email=' ".$email." ' "

Comment: string literals in mysql need to be quoted, ie. `WHERE Email ='zxzx@hotmail.com'`. This would be a good time to read up on sql injection, and how to prevent it using prepared statements - [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: yes thanks guys i just figured it out, dooe.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email ="." '$email' ";

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you are using id then it is integer so no need to put it in quotes('') But if you use email then it is string so you need to write it in quotes('') as follow

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email ='" . $email . "'";
```